# Reading a variable white space delimited table in python

Tags: python, csv, numpy

Right now I am trying to read a table which has a variable whitespace delimiter and is also having missing/blank values. I would like to read the table in python and produce a CSV file. I have tried NumPy, Pandas and CSV libraries, but unfortunately both variable space and missing data together are making it near impossible for me to read the table. The file I am trying to read is attached here:
goo.gl/z7S2Mo

[image: This is how the table looks like]

Would really appreciate if anyone can help me with a solution in python

Comment: That appears to be "fixed width" columns, not variable whitespace delimited with blank values (that would be extremely difficult).

Using sub-strings for each field width and trimming should deal with it.

Comment: I have trying to check if it is fixed width, Its not, because I was trying to import the table in excel and it did not properly take in the table when I suggested that it is fixed width

Comment: I assume Excel was wrong given what my eyes tell me ;-)

Comment: Did you even try splitting the lines on more than a single space? That'd get you pretty close

Comment: I have uploaded a new screenshot. Initially it was not showing the headers. Now with the headers, it can be seen that two columns of data are missing. And this is where I am getting lost on how to process this text table

Comment: @SteveHarris - thanks man!!! Saved my life here. I got it. Its actually fixed width columns so used pandas and read_fwf. Cant thank you enough :) :)

Comment: @cricket_007, thanks for your insights too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numpy module has a function to do just that (see last line):

```
import numpy as np

path = "<insert file path here>/infotable.txt"

# read off column locations from a text editor.
# I used Notepad++ to do that.
column_locations = np.array([1, 38, 52, 61, 70, 78, 98, 111, 120, 127, 132])

# My text editor starts counting at 1, while numpy starts at 0. Fixing that:
column_locations = column_locations - 1

# Get column widths
widths = column_locations[1:] - column_locations[:-1]

data = np.genfromtxt(path, dtype=None, delimiter=widths, autostrip=True)
```

Depending on your exact use case, you may use a different method to get the column widths but you get the idea. `dtype=None` ensures that numpy determines the data types for you; this is very different from leaving out the `dtype` argument. Finally, `autostrip=True` strips leading and trailing whitespace.

The output (`data`) is a [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).

Comment: Numpy thinks these are all strings. Do you need the value, shrs and voting columns to be integers?

Comment: I think if you add the locations of the empty columns it should still work. Try it and feel free to update the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You need your delimiter to be two spaces or more (instead of one space or more).  Here's a solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('infotable.txt',sep='\s{2,}',header=None,engine='python',thousands=',')
```

Result:

```
>>> print(df.head())
                                0             1          2     3      4   5  \
0  ISHARES MORNINGSTAR MID GROWTH           ETP  464288307  3892  41700  SH   
1   ISHARES S&P MIDCAP 400 GROWTH           ETP  464287606  4700  47600  SH   
2               BED BATH & BEYOND  Common Stock  075896100   870  15000  SH   
3              CARBO CERAMICS INC  Common Stock  140781105   950   7700  SH   
4    CATALYST HEALTH SOLUTIONS IN  Common Stock  14888B103  1313  25250  SH   

      6      7  8  9  
0  Sole  41700  0  0  
1  Sole  47600  0  0  
2  Sole  15000  0  0  
3  Sole   7700  0  0  
4  Sole  25250  0  0  

>>> print(df.dtypes)
0    object
1    object
2    object
3     int64
4     int64
5    object
6    object
7     int64
8     int64
9     int64
dtype: object
```